# C# Need help in converting Label's text to Date Time for Access Database

Tags: c#, database, datetime, ms-access, label

I've already looked this to other problems here and to other sites as well but can't seems to fix this.

I'm trying to `UPDATE` existing data in my Access Database.

I have a button that does this. And one of my Identifiers is the text of a Label(This label gets its value from `datagrid_cellcontentclick`). So before I can `UPDATE` my Database, I need to convert first that Label to a `DateTime` format right? So this is what I did / the code in my button:

```
        string dateee = label_todatetime.Text;
        string formatuu = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        //DateTime pleaseconvert = DateTime.ParseExact(dateee, "G", null); //I did try this... tried if the "G" will do the  trick because it means "General Date" which is the same format as my Access Database.. But still didn't work..
        DateTime pleaseconvert = DateTime.ParseExact(dateee, formatuu, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        //MessageBox.Show(pleaseconvert.ToString()); //I just want to see if its outputing the correct format.. 
        try
        {
            accessconnection.Open();

            string mahquery = "UPDATE Account SET" +
                "[UName] = '" + textBox4.Text + "', [Password] = '" + textBox5.Text + "'" +
                " WHERE " +
                "[FName] = '" + textBox1.Text + "' and [MName] = '" + textBox2.Text + "' and [LName] = '" + textBox3.Text + "' and [Added At] = '" + pleaseconvert + "'";
            OleDbCommand accesscommand = new OleDbCommand(mahquery, accessconnection);

            accesscommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            accessconnection.Close();
```

The format of `Added At` in my Access Database is `General Date` and its values are like this: `27/04/2019 14:01:23`(and may label gets the same format right? I just need to convert the `String` to `DateTime`?)... That's why my `formatuu` is `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`... But whenever I click the button it always says

> `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`

Comment: Is the conversion successful? An exception is not thrown?

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to compose an sql query! Use [OleDbParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter) class.

Comment: Output `mahquery` somewhere, to the console for example, and see what the result is.

Comment: Yes, it converts it successfully. Also, I think I've fixed it by accident... the way I've fixed it is not really efficient because I've only used `Parameters.AddWithValue` to the date... if I included the other Texboxes it won't work - `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` error will appear again. And thank you very much for replying very early.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). / Make sure to use parameters that specify the exact data type.

Comment: ohhhh!! so there's a way to directly set the data type using parameters!! thanksss!! gonna try this now.

Comment: It works! though it has a suggestion to use `AddWithValue` instead as the `Add` way is obsolete. Thank you very much! Here's a screenshot to the working code: https://imgur.com/a/RTBJMZG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alexander Petrov's [answer](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Here's the updated/working code:

```
        //string dateee = label_todatetime.Text;
        //string formatuu = "#dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss#";
        ////DateTime pleaseconvert = DateTime.ParseExact(dateee, "G", null);
        //DateTime pleaseconvert = DateTime.ParseExact(dateee, formatuu, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        //MessageBox.Show(pleaseconvert.ToString());
        try
        {
            accessconnection.Open();

            string mahquery = "UPDATE Account SET" +
                "[UName] = @uname, [Password] = @passw" +
                " WHERE " +
                "[FName] = @fname and [MName] = @mname and [LName] = @lname and [Added At] = @dateadded";
            OleDbCommand accesscommand = new OleDbCommand(mahquery, accessconnection);


            //accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@uname", textBox4.Text);
            //accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@password", textBox5.Text);
            //accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@fname", textBox1.Text);
            //accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@mname", textBox2.Text);
            //accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@lname", textBox3.Text);
            //accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@dateadded", label_todatetime.Text);
            accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@uname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
            accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@passw", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;
            accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
            accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
            accesscommand.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
            accesscommand.Parameters.Add("dateadded", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = label_todatetime.Text;
            accesscommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            accessconnection.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Successfuly updated into the database");
```

As you can see, the code is much shorter (if I remove the comments) and this doesn't need `DateTime.ParseExact` to convert `String` to `DateTime` data type. Just used:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("String Parameter Name HERE", SqlDbType."Data Type HERE").Value = "Variable HERE like Texbox1.Text"
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Better use `Parameters.Add("@uname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ...`.

Comment: Changed it. Just read some more articles about `AddWithValue` and `Add`, and learned that `Add` is still superior in terms of my usage as it allows me to directly specify the correct data type of all parameters. Thanks again!!